# get column values into an array

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a database table with columns : name, residence, contact. and I want to retrieve only the values in the 'contact column' into an array. the following code is what I wrote:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
try {
    String sql = "select * from members";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String con = rs.getString("Contact");
        l.add(con);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

but this generates the following result:

```
[0547615632]
[0547615632, 0246687643]
[0547615632, 0246687643, 0558581764]
```

whilst I have only 3 records in the table and each having a contact value.
please how do I write the code so that I can get only a single array displaying the result like this:

```
[0547615632, 0246687643, 0558581764]
```

thank you very much.

Comment: change query to `Select contact from members`

Comment: I did that bro, but I still get the same 3 arrays.

Comment: because you print the **array** on every iteration. either print the array after the loop of only print the **current element**. shown in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the print command out of the while loop:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
try {
    String sql = "select * from members";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String con = rs.getString("Contact");
        l.add(con);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
System.out.println(l);
```

---

**OR** only print the current element in each iteration;

```
List l = new ArrayList();
try {
    String sql = "select * from members";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String con = rs.getString("Contact");
        l.add(con);
        System.out.print(con + " ");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Emre Acer, it worked perfectly. thank you all

Comment: bro please guide me.. am quite new in stack over flow. please where do I go and what link do I have to click on to accept your answer @EmreAcer

Comment: I searched through it bro.. I don't think I have earned the privilege to accept an answer. cos I don't see any options available for me to do that. are u on facebook

Comment: @RodneyNart it doesn't require privilege but its ok my friend. Im happy that i solved your problem. Good luck !